# calculate mean grouped by col number

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes, `df_value` and `df_num`. `df_num` has two columns:`row` and `col` which are the row and column numbers of the value from `df_value` that meets a specific condition. I want to calculate the mean group by `col` in the `df_num`.

I got stuck at group by `col`.

```
df_value<- data.frame('a'=1:3,'b'=2:4,'c'=1:3,'d'=3:5)
df_num <- which(df<4,arr.ind = TRUE)
df_value
a b c d
1 2 1 3
2 3 2 4
3 4 3 5
df_num
row col
1    1
2    1
3    1
1    2
2    2
1    3
2    3
3    3
1    4
```

I want get the mean for `col1`, `col2`, `col3` and `col4`,

```
mean:
 2
 2.5
 2
 3
```

Comment: Why is the mean of column `b` equal to 1.5? Shouldn't it be 2.5? Or am I missing something? Otherwise `apply(df, 2, function(x) mean(x[x < 4]))`. Also, for column 4: the mean should be 3, correct? Unless you want to *replace* values larger or equal to 4 by 0, then do `df_value[ df_value >= 4 ] <- 0 ; colMeans(df_value)`.

Comment: yeah..why would be you need `df_num` at all? You can calculate the mean using `df_value` itself.

Comment: yes, it should be 2.5 and 3. Corrected in the post. Your code works! Can you explain a bit more about apply(df, 2, function(x) mean(x[x < 4])), what does that '2' means? I am new to code.

Comment: @RonakShah Actually, the df_value is a distance matrix, the row and col number of df_value represents the data sample of another dataframe, say df_original. For example, row 1 and col 2 in df_value represent the distance between sample 1 and sample 2 in my df_original dataframe. I  want to select and calculate the mean value for sample 1 and sample 2. I use a simple case here, but seemed not express clearly about my expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **have** to use `df_num` to subset `df_val` and then take `mean` of columns one way is to `split` subsetted `df_value` based on `"col"` column of `df_num` and take `mean` of each list.

```
sapply(split(df_value[df_num], df_num[, "col"]), mean, na.rm = TRUE)

#  1   2   3   4 
#2.0 2.5 2.0 3.0
```

As mentioned in the comments you can directly filter `df_value` to take `mean`

```
sapply(df_value, function(x) mean(x[x<4], na.rm = TRUE))

#  1   2   3   4 
#2.0 2.5 2.0 3.0
```

Comment: Actually, I need one step more. I want to group these row and col number from df_num by 'col' and also include the 'col' itself to make a list. This list represent the row number of a dataframe called df_original. This df_original has only one col and the same number of rows as df_value, my expectation is to use this list as index to get the mean value of the these rows in df_original.

Comment: @Xue You can just convert the output to dataframe using `stack`, `stack(sapply(split(df_value[df_num], df_num[, "col"]), mean, na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tapply` from `base R`

```
tapply(df_value[df_num], df_num[, 'col'], FUN = mean)
#  1   2   3   4 
#2.0 2.5 2.0 3.0
```